# CRM Dynamics 365 - ManyToMany relationships example

Tags: dynamics-crm

We are using CRM dynamics version v9.1 (/api/data/v9.1) and trying to create many-to-many relationship between entities (for example entity 'A' and entity 'B'). As per our CRM API, mapping between these 2 entities is maintained in a 3rd entity which basically keeps ID's of these 2 entities. Below is the reference to create POST request for creating many-to-many relationship which I found from Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/create-update-entity-relationships-using-web-api#create-a-many-to-many-relationship).

But, I am not able to create the many-to-many relationship successfully and get the below error in response-

- **Response**
  {
  "error": {
  "code": "0x80044363",
  "message": "The schema name for type EntityRelationship is not unique. An schema name with same name already exists."
  }
  }
- **Request**
  {"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.ManyToManyRelationshipMetadata",
  "Entity1LogicalName": "A",
  "Entity2LogicalName": "B",
  "IntersectEntityName": "A_B",
  "Entity1IntersectAttribute": "50173618-08e3-df11-806c-005056907671",
  "Entity2IntersectAttribute": "1eac5a1d-3adb-df11-806c-005056907671",
  "IsCustomRelationship": true,
  "IsValidForAdvancedFind": true,
  "SchemaName": "schemaname",
  "SecurityTypes": "None",
  "IsManaged": false,
  "RelationshipType": "ManyToManyRelationship",
  "IntroducedVersion": "1.0",
  "MetadataId": "1d73a50e-47ae-df11-b85b-005056907671",
  "HasChanged": null
  }

Basically, I would like to fully understand how the many-to-many relationship actually works in CRM dynamics 365 and if someone can provide me with a working example that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the N:N relationship you should use the associate/disassociate methods and not the create and delete methods on the intersect entity.

For example:

```
var association = {
    "@odata.id": Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/sample_customtables(ddd99cd3-bec1-4643-af90-c4b21760ec0d)"
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/sample_customtables(c6f35754-6fa8-4e8b-8b58-d4ca958001f4)/sample_sample_customtable_sample_Customtable1/$ref",
    async: true,
    headers: {
        "OData-MaxVersion": "4.0",
        "OData-Version": "4.0",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(association),
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

You can use my tool [Dataverse REST Builder](https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB) to generate the exact request based on your tables (and if you need the raw HTTP request you can export the collection from Dataverse REST Builder to Postman.

Answer (score 0):

As [Guido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2191473/guido-preite) said you should not use the create/delete methods, in fact if you use the Xrm.WebApi it will tell you, you cannot use those methods. For reference, here's how I did it using Xrm.WebApi.

```
async function createAssociation(associationName, primaryEntityName, primaryId, relatedEntities) {
    var manyToManyAssociateRequest = {
        getMetadata: () => ({
            boundParameter: null,
            parameterTypes: {},
            operationType: 2,
            operationName: "Associate"
        }),
        relationship: associationName,
    target: {
        entityType: primaryEntityName,
        id: primaryId
    }}
    
    manyToManyAssociateRequest.relatedEntities = relatedEntities
        
    return await Xrm.WebApi.online.execute(manyToManyAssociateRequest)
}

//studentsToAssign is the return array from a standard Dynamics Lookup that contains the id for a student.
var simpleStudentArray = studentsToAssign.map(student=>{return {entityType: "new_student", id:student.id}})
var res = await createAssociation("new_class_new_student", "new_class", inductionId, simpleStudentArray)
console.log(res) //This is a 204 - no content response
```

This is the POST it generates

```
https://mysite.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/new_classes(649c332d-ca46-ee11-be6f-00224894adf7)/new_class_new_student/$ref

"body": {"@odata.context":"https://mysite.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/$metadata#$ref",
    "@odata.id":"new_students(574af921-62f8-ec11-813d-005056893571)"}
```